# Callback failed: the server did not respond - When trying to update a graph in Dash

Tags: callback, plotly-dash

We are reading the performance data from a table for different releases and creating a line graph to compare different release performance metrics. When the app runs locally, Callbacks fire as they should (on page load), and the app is usable. However, when the app is deployed to a UNIX server the callbacks stop working.

Error: Callback failed: the server did not respond.

at http://server_ip:port/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/dash_renderer.v1_5_1m1593111735.dev.js:33217:11

Comment: This was asked quite a while back, did you happen to solve this by any chance?